# CSS navigation hover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to achieve a hover effect and need some assistance.

I am making a tab looking navigation menu and I want the tab to expand from the top on hover. But my CSS is making the tab expand top and bottom and is moving the parent as well.
Can anyone help me to tweek the code so it dosnt move the parent and only expands at the top on the menu item Thanks in advance!

```
.nav-1 ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.nav-1 ul li a {
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding:16px 22px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.nav-1 ul li a:hover {
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding:22px 22px 26px 22px;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the html as well, and relevant js? And a fiddle world be really helpful.

Comment: Here is the fiddle :) https://jsfiddle.net/jw71ga6h/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jw71ga6h/2/ This will fix the alignment issues (mostly) but you are changing the size of the list items so the parent will expand accordingly. You might need to rethink the way you are going about this.

Comment: Is there a smarter way to do this Paulie_D? If so i am open to suggestions!

Comment: I'd have to think...perhaps something with box shadows but it's gonna made the CSS quite complex.

Comment: I just updated the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jw71ga6h/3/ looks more correct but now they are just moving down rather than up? :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something with using pseudo-elements that seems to fit the requirement.

**Reduced Demo**

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jw71ga6h/6/)

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-1 ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.nav-1 ul li a {
 transition: 0.5s;
 height: 53px;
    padding: 16px 22px;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 font-weight: 400;
    position: relative;
    background-color: inherit; /*  copies bg color for later */
}

.nav-1 ul li a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute; /* doesnt affect parent size */
    top:0%; /* position at top */
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: inherit; /* uses copied bg color */
 transition: 0.5s;
 height: 0px;
    z-index:3;
}

.nav-1 ul li a:hover:after {
 height: 12px; /* add height */
    transform:translateY(-100%); /* adjust location automatically */
}

main {
    height: 250px;
    background: rebeccapurple;
}
.nav-1 li:first-child {background-color: #a0c80a;}
.nav-1 li:nth-child(2) {background-color: #feaf00;}
.nav-1 li:nth-child(3) {background-color: #f13835;}
.nav-1 li:nth-child(4) {background-color: #1ebad8;}
```

```html
 <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-12 nav-1">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">our team</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">facilities</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
<main></main>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can further tweek it so the text moves up 10px with the tab?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the movement only "down" change padding-bottom not the padding-top.

```
.nav-1 ul li a:hover {  padding:16px 22px 26px 22px;}
```

If you change the first value from 16px  to 22px you get the movement.

Comment: I need to move the tabs up, I just updated the fiddle again and the tabs are still opening down rather than up.. https://jsfiddle.net/jw71ga6h/3/

Comment: O, I'm sorry - lost in translation. What do you mean "so it dosnt move the parent and only expands at the top on the menu item " ?